# Can concurrent processes write to a shared database?

Tags: python, database, concurrency

I'm using the Python multiprocessing library to generate several processes that each write to a shared (MongoDB) database.  Is this safe, or will the writes overwrite each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So long as you make sure to create a separate database connection for each worker process, it's perfectly safe to have multiple processes accessing a database at the same time. Any queries they issue which make changes to the database will be applied individually, typically in the order they are received by the database. Under most situations this will be safe, **but**:

- If your processes are all just inserting documents into the database, each insert will typically create a separate object.

  The exception is if you explicitly specify an `_id` for a document, and that identifier has already been used within the collection. This will cause the insert to fail. (So don't do that: leave the `_id` out, and MongoDB will always generate a unique value for you.)
- If your processes are deleting documents from the database, the operation will fail if another process has already deleted the same object. (This is not strictly a failure, though; it just means that someone else got there before you.)
- If your processes are updating documents in the database, things get murkier.

  So long as each process is updating a different document, you're fine.

  If multiple processes are trying to update the same document at the same time, you start needing to be careful. Updates which replace values on an object will be applied in order, which may cause changes made by one process to inadvertently be overwritten by another. You should be careful to avoid specifying fields that you don't intend to change. Using MongoDB's [update operators](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/) may be helpful to perform complex operations atomically, such as changing the numeric values of fields.

Note that "at the same time" doesn't necessarily mean that operations are occurring at *exactly* the same time. It means more generally that there's an "overlap" in the time two processes are working with the same document, e.g.

```
Process A                    Process B
---------                    ---------
Reads object from DB         ...
working...                   Reads object from DB
working...                   working...
updates object with changes  working...
                             updates object with changes
```

In the above situation, it's possible for some of the changes made by process A to inadvertently be overwritten by process B.

Comment: What happens if you use the same connection for all the worker processes?

Comment: @Jessica Bad things. (Multiple processes may try to write to the connection at the same time, and MongoDB will get a jumbled mess and probably just drop the connection.) So don't do that. :)

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes it is perfectly reasonable (and actually preferred) to let your database worry about the concurrency of your database operations.

Any relevant database driver (MongoDB included) will handle concurrent operations for you automatically.